# .NET WebClient: Where is DownloadString?

Tags: .net, webclient

I'm probably missing something here, but when I use WebClient and look for the DownloadString method (as found in a book example), I only see DownloadStringAsync.

What Import am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Silverlight? Only the Async version is available in Silverlight.  Otherwise, the .NET 4 Framework and below (except 1.x) have the DownloadString() method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200.aspx

Comment: Ahh...that explains it. Yes. Messing with Silverlight coming from WPF.

Answer (score 0):

as indicated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx), it looks like the `DownloadString` method is part of `System.Net`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you're creating a Silverlight application. In that case it is a normal thing: you will find usually only asynchronous methods in Silverlight applications; this makes your UI more responsive because operations will be executed in another thread without blocking it.

Try to create a desktop application (Console Application, WPF, etc.) and you will find the method you're looking for.